# Search API, create documents and indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search

I need help in the search API

I am Brazilian and I'm using the google translator to communicate.

My question is:

For each item in the datastore persisted I create a document and an index?
And for those objects that are already persisted in the datastore, I go all the bank to create a document and an index for each, if I want to search for Search API?
I am using java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's reasonable to use the Search API to search for objects that are also stored in the Datastore.  You can create a Search document for each Datastore entity (so that there's a one-to-one correspondence between them).  But you don't need to use a separate Search Index for each one: all the Search documents can be added to one index.  Or, if you have a huge number of documents, and if there is some natural partitioning between them, you could distribute them over some modest number of indexes.  Assuming you can know via some external means which (single) index to choose for searching, preventing them from getting too big can help performance.

I've tried to answer the question that I *think* you're asking.  It's difficult for me to understand the English that the Google translator has produced.  In particular, what does "I go all the bank ..." mean?

Comment: Answered yes Alan, thank you for your disposal.
The "" I go all the bank "that is said:
For objects have persisted, I have to select all and add one by one int the index?